# Shadows different in viewport and render

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, lighting, toon-shading, settings

When I use eevee to render this simple hand model, the shadows look different in the viewport versus the render, as shown in the attached image. There is no difference in subdivision levels, viewport vs render visibility settings or render settings as far as I can tell. I've also looked through other people's questions and found no answers. Anyone have any idea why this is happening?

[image]

I could simply do a render viewport image render, but I'm also trying to use freestyle with this and that isn't something that can be rendered in the viewport.

Comment: Your image shows your viewport is in "Material Preview" mode which usually has its own lighting setup which is different from the "Rendered" mode lighting

Answer (score 0):

As Ron said, the Material Preview by default uses it's own lighting. If you'd like it to use the lights in your scene you can check Scene Lights and Scene World in the Viewport Shading dropdown, then the material preview should look the same as the rendered view (if you are rendering with Eevee)

[image: Viewport Shading]